# angular2. how can I make a route append queryParam with exists params?

Tags: angular, router

When I have URL : http://stack.com/abc?code=1
And I would like to get URL like : http://stack.com/abc?code=1&page=1

I would like to use this kind of code

```
let navigationExtras;
navigationExtras = {
  {preserveQueryParams: true},
  {queryParams: {page: 1}}
};

this.router.navigate(['/abc'], navigationExtras);
```

preserveQueryParams means using exists params.
and queryParams means append new params.
But using both at together are not work now.

Any good idea? without using "this.route.subscribe(...)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change existing params or append new ones without using `preserveQueryParams` if you copy them from the `ActivatedRoute` (which can be injected in the constructor).

```
const currentParams = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
this.router.navigate(["/abc"], {
   queryParams: {...currentParams, "page": "1"},
});
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. some code is not work for me. so I use like this : const currentParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParams; this.router.navigate(["/abc"], {
   queryParams: Object.assign(currentParams, {"page": "1"})
});

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `preserveQueryParams` option in `NavigationExtras`, also correct object like below.

```
let navigationExtras;
navigationExtras = {
  preserveFragment: true,
  preserveQueryParams: true, //added parameter
  queryParams: {page: 1}
};

this.router.navigate([this.route.url], navigationExtras);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer!  I left wrong code. so I changed. My question was that It can not work preserveQueryParams and queryParams together.